# SQL - How to get a max value from a table and add it into another (sqlite3)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Just like the title says, how would i get the maximun value from one table and add it into a field into another table from the same database:

**I currently have my main table "users":**

*username* | *password* |  *Email* | *Highscore 1* | *Highscore 2* |  *Highscore 3* |

I also have my other tables :

**"user_scores1":**

*username* | *Score 1* |

**"user_scores2":**

*username* | *Score 2* |

**"user_scores3":**

*username* | *Score 3* |

- The "user_scores" tables contains all the scores of all the users (for the 3 different game modes) whenever they play. Whenever the user finishes the game for a particular game mode, a new score gets added into a new row as well as their username associaed to it, to the table of scores for that gamemode
- I want to filter out all the scores from a user (e.g user1) and then get their highest score from the game modes, (e.g filtering out all the scores of user1 from the user_scores1 table)
- With this, i want to get the highest score of that specific user from that specific table  , and add it into my main table "users" in the appropite field (e.g like the previous example ,filtering out all the scores of user1 from the user_scores1 table, then getting the highest score and adding that score into my main table "users" into highscores1 where the username is user1 )

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update users
    set highscore1 = (select max(score) from user_scores1 us where us.username = users.name),
        highscore2 = (select max(score) from user_scores2 us where us.username = users.name),
        highscore3 = (select max(score) from user_scores3 us where us.username = users.name);
```